# Relation between rise and fall times and capacitance

Tags: capacitance, rise-time, sample-and-hold

So I'm currently reading the datasheet of the Motorola 68hc000 CPU and I want to be able to estimate how many devices I can plug to the bus directly before I encounter issues.

So first things first, the datasheet is confusing for me, but maybe it's because I'm still learning. I know that all outputs must drive the bus signals and the bus has setup and hold requirements to ensure proper operation.

My guess is that in order to make those times signals must rise and fall fast enough. For that, there has to be a maximum capacitance that the bus can accept before proper operation isn't guaranteed anymore. But by reading the datasheet this isn't obvious to me.

Take the Address pins of the CPU, according to the datasheet, those can source 3.2 mA of current when low, but I see no such metric for high.

I also see a "load capacitance" metric in the DC Specification of the datasheet that says 130 pF , is that the max and that should be the end of it?

Should I just add pull up resistors for the bus to ensure that all signals have fast enough rise times? For the value my guess is that I need to ensure that no low output is required to source more current than what the spec days and that helps me find to lowest possible resistance value, but that still leaves me with the question:

How can I find in any of these datasheets a metric that helps me calculate what is the maximum capacitance I can have in the bus.

You can assume that all lines are electrically short enough to not see transmission line effects.

Disclaimer: I'm a self-taught hobbyist.

Comment: Look up how to calculate fanout

Comment: To meet other specs, meet capacitance load specs. Don't forget that a connector, just by itself all alone, represents some capacitance. So if you are using connectors for add-in boards, you've got to account for all that, too. And it's not small (usually.)

Comment: If in doubt, add buffers. Also note that the specs are what the manufacturer guarantees, not drop-dead values. You can exceed the given 130pF of capacitance and assuming the rest of your circuit can tolerate that, then the cpu will still work. Putting pull-ups is not a great solution with cmos as the drive is fairly symmetrical vs ttl and nmos devices that had better sink specs than sourcing. So guesstimate your capacitance based on track length and each of the devices connected. If you think you’re running too close to the edge, then add buffers. Or build it and measure.